# AS3 - Skip not Move

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a frogger game in AS3 and when you press up, down, left and right, you "skip" a certain amount of space instead of gradually moving there like in most platformers now. How would I be able to do this?

Currently he moves up left, down and right on their respective keys. But he gradually moves there, not skipping the amount of space like in the real frogger.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Code:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
        trace("frogger up");
        player.y -= 5;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
        trace("frogger down");
        player.y += 5;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        trace("frogger left");
        player.x -= 5;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            trace("frogger right");
        player.x += 5;
        }
}
```

Comment: Simply increase the amount of pixels you move each time you press a key? e.g. 50 instead of 5.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is to increase the X and Y with a certain amount like as Marty said in the comment, with 50.. or you could create two variables, let's name them `xPosition` & `yPosition`.
When holding down the keys, you would just increase/decrease these variables by 1, and then call a positioning function which would calculate the new position of the player depending on the `xPosition` and `yPosition` 's values and of course the grid sizes.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
var xPosition:int = 0;
var yPosition:int = 0;
var gridWidth:int = 32;
var gridHeight:int = 32;
function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
        yPosition--;
        repositionPlayer();
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
        yPosition++;
        repositionPlayer();
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        xPosition--;
        repositionPlayer();
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        xPosition++;
        repositionPlayer();
    }
}
function repositionPlayer():void{
    player.x = gridWidth*xPosition;
    player.y = gridHeight*yPosition;
}
```

This gives you a big advantage in case you want to change the grid size.